# How can I make a website with dynamic features with wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, content-management-system

As I am a novice in web development field,I wanted to clarify some questions running in my head.
1. I want to make a website with dynamic features with or without pluggins.Dynamic features can be like anything under the sun.Is it possible that I can make a website using Wordpress(which is mostly considered as blogging platform).

2.Should I learn any of the frameworks like Django or rails,if yes why(its obvious I would have to learn CSS,Ajax,Javascript,PHP)?

3.I don't want to learn drupal as its time for learning curve is very higher than that of wordpress.(Yes I can think of Joomla,but I don't know how much time it takes to learn from scratch as compared to wordpress)

4.Again I want to repeat, the dynamic features can be like anything under the sun whatever I can think of.Will it be fully customizable after I get my hands perfectly on learning some languages and frameworks.I know there are many pluggins and themes in Wordpress.

5.I also want to make a rich platform for advertisement which will be commercial.Is it possible that I make a model of advertisement which is in my mind which can link to any other websites,blogs,people(users).

Comment: It sounds like you answered your own question- wordpress plugins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer to your long question is, yes, WordPress is a good place to start.  As a relative beginner it will help you create a simple website at first, but will allow you to add complexity as your coding skills and knowledge of the platform increase.  If you want to create Software as a Service applications, you should choose something else to get into (Ruby on Rails or asp.net would be good choices), but if you just want to create a nice, complex, dynamic website WordPress is a great way to go.

So to answer your questions specifically 1.Yes. 2.  You don't need to to begin.  3.  Not a question, but I basically agree.  4. Wordpress will not limit you much initially.  It will limit you more than, say, Ruby on Rails, but it will probably take your coding skills years to "outgrow" WordPress.  5.  That should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

In regards to your question about learning frameworks, if you're completely new to web design, I would have to highly suggest the PHP route... it's much much easier to learn and is a lot less complicated that Django. The problems and ideas you come up with during have been encountered 1000 times before and are usually easily search-able and fix-able.